# Container structure for class containing a class acting as an identifier

Tags: c++, design-patterns, c++11

For the following set of classes

```
class Identifier; // can be used as a key
class Data;
class MoreData;

class Object {
  Identifier id_;
  Data data_;
  MoreData moreData_;
};
```

What is a good design for the data store of a database of `Object`s class?  Having tried

```
std::set<Object>
```

This keeps the encapsulation of the Object class abstraction but the act of using the `Identifier` member to manipulate (e.g., find, insert, etc.) is clunky.  Having tried

```
std::map<Identifier, std::pair<Data, MoreData>>
```

The semantics around using Identifier as a key are much more natural but this breaks the Object class encapsulation and manipulation requires constructing Object instances from the parts.

Is there a better choice here that does not suffer from either of the shortcoming of the above approaches (or mitigates them)?  Nothing set in stone so refactor of Object or adding a method, etc., are appreciated responses.  Boost fine as well if nothing better exists in the standard.

Comment: Can you provide a little context?  Without it, I'd say combine `Data` and `MoreData` into a new class to act as the `map`'s value.  Is the `Object` class absolutely necessary as it currently exists?

Comment: Indeed, we need to know more. We don't know if you want to reflect the collection changes in database (sth like Active Object) or separate DAO will be ok ?

Comment: @Gracchus isn't that the same as essentially pushing the pair in the second option back into the Object class?  Is that what you're suggesting?

Comment: @Gaskoin I am not sure I am familiar with all the terms you used.  That said, the types of operations that will be happening to the database object often are things like insertion and deletion based on finding the right Identifier (or occasionally based on something else in the data objects) and those should be reflected in the current state of the database.  Object data look-up and changing based on Identifier (and again occasionally other criteria related to the data).  Does that provide help as to the context?

Comment: @Gracchus While the Object class as it is currently is not necessary something that holds the all of the information about a single "object" is.

Comment: @bpw1621 I hear you, and I think I had the exact same issue, yet when I stepped back and could determine that the key and value didn't need to be in the same class for the simple fact that they are connected via the `map` with the added benefit of key uniqueness, I just used that.  I'm no c++ master by any means, but my rational self prefers laziness unless if there's a good reason not to. :)  Accessing by key, and creating a few extra functions that can search by `map` value values seems to work for me every time, or am I missing something that requires a single class to hold all?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at [Boost.Multi-Index](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html), which allows you to specify `Object::id_` as the key.  Something like:

```
boost::multi_index_container<
    Object,
    boost::multi_index::indexed_by<
        boost::multi_index::ordered_unique<
            boost::multi_index::member<Object, Identifier, &Object::id_>
        >   
    >   
>;
```